Do the libraries time, _thread and random have their own versions?
I need to determine the versions of all libraries that I used in a project (made with PyCharm), but  the libraries math, random, _thread and time are not listed as installed packages and also not included in the list given out by pip list.
Apparently, that is the case for math, because it does not carry its own version, and instead depends on the python version used (3.10, in this case). Does this also apply to the other three libraries I am having trouble with? And if not, what other ways are there to determine each one's installed version?

Yes, you are correct in your assumption that the libraries math, random, _thread, and time are not listed as installed packages in your environment because they are part of the Python Standard Library. These modules come bundled with Python itself, so they don't have independent versions. The versions of these libraries are tied to the version of Python you're using.
If you're curious about the specific version of a standard library module in your environment, you can check it indirectly by using the version attribute, although not all modules have this attribute. For example:
import sys
import time

print(sys.version)
print(time.__file__) 

